# high chart- how to add array in custom dataLabels formatter

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

When I add `allVolumnData[indexArray]` in datalabel formatter and click on print or save as image the label transforms into undefined datalabel can you please help me with solution.

```
   plotOptions: {
      line: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML:true,
            formatter: function() { 
                plotHtml= '<div class="datalabel" style="position: 
                relative;"><b>'+this.point.y+'</div><br/><div 
                class="datalabelInside" style="position: absolute; 
                top: 45px; color:#008000; ">
                <b>'+allVolumnData[indexArray]+'</div>';
                indexArray++;
                return plotHtml;
            },
       },
       enableMouseTracking: true,
       color: volumnColor
    }
}
```

Comment: when u console.log(allVolumnData)it shows [149670, 154908, 160130]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Shahbaaz/yw8wugLr/

Comment: u can check out here the full code and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have, is that you assign `var indexArray=0;` at the beginning of your js code. When the chart is first rendered it has `indexes 0, 1, 2...` However, when you press print, it re-renderes the chart, which means `indexes` are `6, 7, 8...` and therefore undefined in the `allVolumnData` array.

If you add an event that sets `indexArray = 0` when the chart is re-rendered you can avoid this issue. Like this:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    render: function() {
      indexArray = 0;
    }
  }
},
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/yw8wugLr/1/

**API on chart.events.render:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render